# How to properly use Virtual Keyboard with Kivy on Android device

Tags: python, android, kivy, virtual-keyboard

I have a simple python/kivy code like this (found on this webiste) which demondstrates how to show custom Virtual Keyboard.

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.11.1")
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("kivy", "keyboard_mode", 'dock')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


Window.size = (1080 / 3, 2127 / 3)


class Calc(TextInput):
    def _keyboard_close(self):
        pass

    def setup_keyboard(self):
        kb = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_close, self)
        if kb.widget:
            kb.widget.layout = 'numeric.json'
            kb.widget.font_size = 100
            kb.widget.height = 500


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Calc()
        root.setup_keyboard()
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Unfortunately when I transfer it to apk file and run it on my Android device, then I have two keyboards on the screen. One Virtual keyboard and over it there is Android system keyboard.

Is there a way how to get rid of this android system keyboard?

Thank for answer.

Comment: of course before running on Android device I remove window.size line

Comment: So did you manage to get rid of the android keyboard? Currently I'm trying to figure out if the android keyboard is open or not, the conclusion to your problem may be the answer to mine.

Comment: unfortunately not